# JQuery load() cannot send page by email in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, load

I have a page that, on load, displays a "spinner" gif while it retrieves the content using jQuery's load() method.

The problem for Internet Explorer users is they cannot see the content in an email when using IE's built-in "Send\Page by Email", most likely because the content is loaded to a div.

Does anyone have a way to work around this? Is there a different method I should be using?

Here is the code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$().ready(function() {
  $('#result').load("/reports/default.do?method=report123", function(responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
            if (textStatus == "success") {
                $('#loading').hide();
                $('#result').show();
            }
            if (textStatus == "error") {
               alert("page could not be loaded.");
            }
        });
    });
    </script>

    <div id="loading"><img src="../images/ajax-loader.gif" alt="loading" id="loading"/></div>

    <div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: Not related to question, but `$().ready` is depreciated and will not work in newer versions of jQuery. It should be `$(document).ready`

Comment: ... or just `$(function($) { ... });`

Answer (score 1):

Most (if not all) email clients, including gmail, hotmail, etc remove javascript from the email contents.

This is to prevent people sending an email that can contain possible exploits.

The page functions just the same as if you viewed it with javascript turned off in your browser.

Any reason why you need to load the content via an ajax load, instead of just including it in the page via server side code?

**Edit:**

For email recipients (and non JS users), you could try:

```
<noscript><a href="/reports/default.do?method=report123" title="report123">View the report.</a></noscript>
```

Put that inside the existing load div and change the loading image to only show on page load:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#loading').show();
        $('#result').load("/reports/default.do?method=report123", function(responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
        if (textStatus == "success") {
            $('#loading').hide();
            $('#result').show();
        }
        if (textStatus == "error") {
           alert("page could not be loaded.");
        }
    });
});
</script>

<div id="loading">
    <noscript><a href="/reports/default.do?method=report123" title="report123">View the report.</a></noscript>
    <img src="../images/ajax-loader.gif" alt="loading" id="loading" style="display:none;"/></div>

<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: We do it so a "loading" image will display while the data loads, otherwise the user would have a blank page displayed until the results were finally fetched.

Comment: I guess that content takes a while to process then?

Comment: I've done some more investigating into this. When requesting content using either the $.ajax, $.get or .load method in jQuery, I assumed that since it was retrieving content and coming back as part of the DOM, that the content would be available when the user attempts to "Save Page As" or "Send Page By Email" within the browser. Because the content is external, it doesn't save it? Does anyone have a work-around instead of doing a redirect to the loaded URL to get the full content of the page?

Comment: It would work but I am trying to prevent the user from having to "run" the report and then click on a additional link. Appreciate the idea though gscragg!